# How to programmatically add CSS class to ASP.NET CheckBoxlist html table items

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

How can I programmatically (i.e. dynamically) add CSS class to ASP.NET CheckBoxlist html table elements.

For example, I want the "table", "tr", "td" tags output below (viewed from browser View Source) to contain CSS styles.

```
<table id="CheckBoxList1" class="myCss1 myCss1row myCss1col myCss1table__checkbox--row">
<tr>
    <td><input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$0" >value="Item1" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_0">MyItem1</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$1" >value="Item2" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_1">MyItem2</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$2" >value="Item3" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_2">MyItem3</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="CheckBoxList1_3" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$3" >value="Item4" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_3">MyItem4</label></td>
</tr>
```

-=========== DESIRED Output when view in Browser View Source =================

```
<table id="CheckBoxList1" class="myCss1 myCss1row myCss1col myCss1table__checkbox--row">
<tr class="myCss1row">
<td class="myCss1col"><input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$0" value="Item1" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_0">BitBucket</label></td>
</tr><tr class="myCss1row">
    <td class="myCss1col"><input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$1" value="Item2" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_1">Confluence</label></td>
</tr><tr class="myCss1row">
    <td class="myCss1col"><input id="CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$2" value="Item3" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_2">FECRU</label></td>
</tr><tr class="myCss1row">
    <td class="myCss1col"><input id="CheckBoxList1_3" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$3" value="Item4" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_3">JIRA</label></td>
</tr>
```

--======================================================================

Below is the code snippet:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ToolName" DataValueField="ToolName" CssClass="myCss1 myCss1row myCss1col myCss1table__checkbox--row"">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ToolName], [ToolCost], [PDate], [ToolURL], [ToolLink], [ToolUrl] FROM [ToolInfo]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks for your reply in advance!

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to style table rows and cells?

Comment: Can you provide the ASP.NET code of the <`asp:CheckBoxList>`?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. CheckBoxList won't always render a table, so this is considered an implementation detail, and is hidden from the developer. Unless you want to go really hacky and create a new control inherited from CheckBoxList. Then you'll have full control over the markup and can add whatever classes you'd like to.

However for most use cases this would definitely be an overkill. Why not apply style to your rows and cells using just css selectors?

```
.myCss1table__checkbox--row tr {
    /* same stuff you would put in myCss1row */
}

.myCss1table__checkbox--row td {
    /* same stuff you would put in myCss1col */
}
```

Alternatively you can use javascript and assign these classes on page load (jQuery used below):

```
$(function(){
    $(".myCss1table__checkbox--row tr").addClass("myCss1row");
    $(".myCss1table__checkbox--row td").addClass("myCss1col");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access each [`ListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [`CheckBoxList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx) in the code behind after the list is databound and you can manipulate each item's `class` property.

This will not allow you to apply classes to each specific DOM element, but only on the top-level one. In order to apply styles to child DOM elements, I suggest using CSS selectors:

```
.class-applied td {
    /* style definition */
}
```